# Conditionally set value of column in MySQL select query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a simple query in MySQL

```
select AGE, NAME from Members;
```

which returns,

```
20 ABC
11 PQR
21 XYZ
16 REW
```

I need to conditionally select NAME from Members, i.e if AGE is less then 18 I need to print MINOR. So my output will be

```
20 ABC
11 MINOR
21 XYZ
16 MINOR
```

I know I should do this programmatically, but I am dumping the output directly to a file in CSV format using

```
 INTO OUTFILE '$random_file_name' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

What are my options in MySQL query itself to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select AGE,
       case when AGE < 18 
            then 'MINOR' 
            else NAME 
       end as NAME
from Members
```